# How pass parameter from Jquery Select2 plugin to asp.net web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, jquery-select2

I have 2 dropdowns first for costcenter and second for Items. here items dropdown is filled based on costcenter.
How can I call my Items web service on change of costcenter dropdown.

I want  to pass selected value of costcenter  dropdown to my asmx webservice.
I am using select2 plugin for above rwo dropdowns.
please help me............

Answer (score 0):

## Bind the `element`'s on change event :

```
$("#elementId").on("change",function(){
    //This will return selected value
    var selectedValue=$(this).("option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/getData',
        data: '{ val:+'selectedValue+'}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {

        }
    });

});
```

In your code behind file:-

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getData(string val)
{
    //Call your web-service with val as your selected drop down value 
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/ptZhF/1/

Comment: Sir I want to pass this selected value in my asmx service which is called at change event of first $("#elementId") using select2 plugin..